# FirstOrDefault() breaks FetchType=join with Linq to NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

If i do

```
Session.Linq<MyClass>().Where(x => x.Id = someId).FirstOrDefault();
```

where `MyClass` has a set of eager loaded child object on it, the `FirstOrDefault()` seems to prevent this from working by adding a `TOP 1` to the SQL.

Is this just a bug (feature?) in Linq2NH (which i understand is being rewritten) or am I missing something?

Is there a preferred alternative which works properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug, in my opinion FirstOrDefault is a pretty well defined Linq operator and it has nothing to do with eager/lazy loading, so it should not break it.

I guess there are lots of such nuances, which cause that the library is not production ready. I suggest submitting the bug the the devs.

Falling back to DetachedCriteria (or HQL) in this case is the only option in my opinion.

Comment: It is a bug, this also helps explain it: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/02/CombatingTheSelectN1ProblemInNHibernate.aspx